# AngularJS - Service call within the callback of another service does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement some code to controll a popup to show loading information. 
For this I have implemented a small piece of code to control my popup and set its visibility and its content.

I am using the PopupController to set the behaviour of the Popup Element. The PopupService is used to connect the PopupController with the ApplicationController.

**PopupService:**

```
app.service("PopupService", function(){
     return {content: "", isVisible: false}
});
```

**PopupController:**

```
app.controller('PopupController', function($scope, PopupService){
    $scope.isVisible = PopupService.isVisible;
    $scope.content = PopupService.content;
})
```

**ApplicationController**

```
app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope, PopupService, DataService){
    PopupService.isVisible = true;          <-- Works fine
    PopupService.content = "Loading Data";  <-- Works fine

    DataService.query(function(list){
        $scope.list = list;
        PopupService.isVisible = false;     <-- Does not work
    })
})
```

Within the callback of the DataService the call to PopupService does not work.
I guess I do have some scope issues but I cannot solve this.

Can anyone help please?

thanks

Comment: try a $scope.$apply wrapping your non functioning statements

Comment: Try binding it to the scope: `$scope.PopupService = PopupService;`, then in your callback `$scope.PopupService.isVisible = false;`. I think $scope.$apply() will simply update the scope (which PopupService is not part of). I could be wrong though, some things about services still puzzle me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried to assign the PopupService to the local scope but this does not change anything.
I tried to $apply the $scope after the assignment but got an error I do not know how to handle.

Comment: The reference to this error is https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog

I can not call a second $apply procedure within this functions.

Comment: Please show the DataService code.

Comment: Hi there,

Sorry for the delay. 
My Dataservice looks something like this.

    module.factory("DataService", ['$resource', function($resource){
        return $resource(path + api + '/data/', null)
    }])